# Are there any apps for Mac that have Photos extensions?

Tags: photos.app

[Apple's website](https://www.apple.com/osx/photos/) for the Mac version of photos.app states that external editors and filter apps (extensions) will be able to be used. The iPad version achieves this, but I note they don't seem to be reflected to the photo stream.

Are there any apps that support this functionality yet on the Mac?

Comment: For iOS: Photo Stream uploads a copy of the photo at the time it was added to your Camera Roll. Assuming the edits you make don't actually generate a new copy of the photo (like "Save as" would do on a computer), Photo Stream will not reflect changes.

Comment: Also, the iOS photos app and Mac photos app are not the same thing. iOS Photos has had extensions since iOS 8 launched back in September 2014.

Comment: The behaviour seems a bit inconsistent to me. I edited an existing old photo on my iPhone with ProCam today and those modifications made it right back to my Mac Photostream. Perhaps not all apps behave properly yet.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this is coming in El Capitan; it was announced at WWDC.

Reported on multiple news sites, but an example snippet from [here](https://tidbits.com/article/15717): "...support for third-party editing extensions that will be available from the Mac App Store and accessible within Photos itself. It doesn’t sound as though that will enable external editing in Adobe Photoshop, say, but it will go a long way toward enhancing the editing capabilities of Photos."